# Riemann Integrability - Piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

> For  $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,  & 0\le x\le1 \\  2, & 1<x\le2
> \end{cases}$
>
> Use the definition of the Riemann Integral to show that $f$ is Riemann
>   Integrable over $[0,2]$.

It was suggested that I use the partition $(0, 1-\epsilon, 1+ \epsilon, 2)$ and let $ \epsilon\rightarrow 0$. Unfortunately, I am unsure how to do this. Any guidance would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea using the partition of the hint, $P=(t_{0}=0,t_{1}=1-\epsilon,t_{2}=1+\epsilon,t_{3}=2)$, is that$\\$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=$\sum_{0}^{2}(M_{s}(f)-m_{s}(f))(t_{k+1}-t_{k})=2\epsilon$.
Therefore if $\epsilon$ tends to $0$ we have U(f,P)=L(f,P) then f is integrable.